# Убрать из списка повторяющиеся элементы при помощи groupby

Tags: python, group-by

Я анализирую файл xls и копирую из него элементы столбцов, которые соответствуют моему условию. Затем эти элементы я записываю в список и вывожу в файл. В некоторых случаях элементы повторяются несколько раз, вот от этого повторения мне и необходимо избавиться. Для этого я пытался использовать модуль `itertools` и его итератор `groupby`. Но в итоге на выходе я вижу, что имена разбиты по одному символу (а должны быть буквенно-цифровые символы вида XY_ABCD14).

```
import xlrd
from itertools import groupby

excel_data_file = xlrd.open_workbook('./file.xls')

sheet_count = excel_data_file.nsheets
print(sheet_count)

for sheetno in range(sheet_count):
    sheet = excel_data_file.sheet_by_index(sheetno)
    print("Sheet name:", sheet.name)
    row_number = sheet.nrows
    print('row_number', row_number)

ind_lst = sheet.col_values(0)
name_lst = sheet.col_values(2)

f = open('new1.txt', 'w')
for i in range(0, len(name_lst)):
    if name_lst[i] == 'ZZZZ':
        b = name_lst[i]
        c = ind_lst[i]
        new_c = [word for word, group in groupby(c)]

        print(new_c)
        #f.write(new_c + '\n')
f.close()
```

При попытке записи списка `new_c` в файл (`f.write(new_c + '\n')`), выдается ошибка о несоответствии типов:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Зачем groupby? Может просто эти элементы копировать во множество, а не список?

Comment: 1. Используйте множества (set), вместо списка в list comprehension. 2. Интерпретатор правильно ругается - вы при записи в файл пытаетесь прибавить перевод строки к списку. Либо приведите список к строке (join), либо записывайте перевод строки отдельным оператором, либо воспользуйтесь функцией print вместо write для записи в файл (тогда перевод строки не понадобится)

Comment: Ошибка у вас выдается, потому что вы пытаетесь соединить список и строку. Вы наверное хотите перечень слов через запятую вывести. В этом случае сделаете так: `f.write(', '.join(new_c) + '\n')`

Comment: При использовании set на выходе вместо A1_BCDEFGH2 я получаю {'G', 'E', '_', 'C', '2', 'H', 'F', 'D', '1', 'B', 'A'} и так для всех остальных элементов.